# How can I replace varchar to table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replace

[[image]]

I want to replace these column numbers <1700>/(<1027>-<1018>-<1019>-<1022>-<1020>)

Node column name

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how someone could answer this beacuse I do NOT even understand what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(2000) = '<1027>-<1018>';
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(2000) = @source;

DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (
    [Data] INT
    , [Replacement] BIGINT 
);

INSERT INTO @YourTable ([Data], [Replacement])
VALUES 
(1700, -251158)
,(1027, 1482018)
,(1018, 75451);

SELECT @result = REPLACE(@result,CONCAT('<',[Data],'>'), [Replacement])
FROM @YourTable

SELECT @result
-- OUTPUT: 1482018-75451
```